# menu flexbox se me comporta de modo extraño con el jquery

Tags: html, jquery, menú, responsive, flexbox

el caso es que tengo un menú principal con sus items puestos en horizontal y cuando lo pongo en visión más pequeña, para tablet o móvil el menú se me pone vertical(un item encima de otro). Lo que pasa es que también lleva una pestaña de menú para que este se expanda o encoja en caso de verse en pantallas pequeñas. Pues bien, cuando paso de pantalla pequeña a pantalla grande el menú se queda vertical y se tendría que ver horizontal de nuevo. Ocurre que al desplegar el código hacia la versión de escritorio desde el móvil los items se ponen verticales y no horizontales. Parece como si no respetara las medias queries. Dejo el código.

```js
    /controlar el toggle menu
    $("#toggle-menu").click(function(){
     
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
      
     
     
    });
     
    $(window).on("resize", function(){
     
        if($(this).width()>768){
     
            $("#toggle-menu").next().show();
      
            
        }
     
     
    });
```

```css
    .menu{
    padding-left:0px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: steelblue;
     
     
    }
     
    @media  (min-width: 768px){
        .menu{
        display: flex;
        
     
        }
     
        .menu li{
        flex: auto;
        text-align: center;
      border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
       
        }
     
        #toggle-menu{
            background: steelblue;
            line-height: 2.5;
            color: aliceblue;
            padding: left;
            font-size: .9em;
            cursor: pointer;
            display:none;
        }
     
    }
    .menu a{
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 3;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: .9em;
    }
    .menu a:hover{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    .menu li {
     
     
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);   
     
    }
     
     
    #toggle-menu{
    background: steelblue;
    line-height: 2.5;
    color: aliceblue;
    padding: left;
    font-size: .9em;
    cursor: pointer;
     
     
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
            <div id="toggle-menu"> MENU </div> 
                <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="productos.php">todos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="productos.php?genero=1">hombre</a></li>
                        <li><a href="productos.php?genero=2">mujer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="productos.php?genero=3">unisex</a></li>   
                        <li><a href="#">login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">registro</a></li>
                    </ul>
             
                </nav>
```

Comment: No estoy muy seguro, pero quizá sea por como pones en @media, debido a que este usa "@media screen"  o "@media" only screen no se si por ello.

Comment: No era eso. Pero gracias por contestar.